# How to count the number of inputs entered through the read command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

The simple function I wrote asks for 3 numbers to be entered. I want to write a while loop that repeatedly asks for input if the number of inputs entered is not equal to 3.

I don't know the correct command to find the number of inputs entered. Help, please?

```
testfunction() {

    read -p "Enter 3 numbers: " num1 num2 num3
    while [[ the number of inputs != 3 ]]; do
        # ask for inputs again
    done
    # once 3 inputs, do the rest of function here
}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask for a number within the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading an array instead, then count the array members.

```
testfunction() {

    declare -a nums=()
    while [[ ${#nums[@]} -ne 3 ]]; do
        read -p "Enter 3 numbers: " -a nums
    done
    # do something else
    declare -p nums

}
```

If for some reason you don't like arrays, you might try using positional parameters:

```
testfunction() {

    set - ""
    while [[ $# -ne 3 ]]; do
        read -p "Enter 3 numbers: " nums
        set - $nums
    done
    # do something else
    declare -p nums

}
```

Comment: Is this possible without using an array?

Comment: Sure. I've added one to the answer. I think the array is more elegant and is probably safer.

Comment: What does the line: `declare -p nums` do?

Comment: `declare -p` just shows you the contents of a variable unambiguously, regardless of type. You can "do something else" or "do the rest of the function" as you see fit. :)

Comment: How do I "expand" the contents of `$nums`? If I want to check if at least 1 of the number entered is not within the range of 1-10, inclusive...

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran, if `$nums` is an array, `${nums[@]}` expands to each of its members. If `$nums` is a string of space-separated words, you can `set` to set positional parameters, as I did in my second example. In either case, you can use a `for` loop to step through the values to test against a range.

Comment: Seems like using an array is the way to go. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If I want to exit the while loop upon an entering an input string such as “quit”, do I just write the if statement inside the while loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204151/discussion-between-binibiningtinamoran-and-ghoti).